# Handling CRUD for look-up tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating the admin portion of a project. Specifically, I am wanting to allow the users to update the look-up tables for their areas of interest.

All of my look-up tables have the same structure:

> ```
> TypeX
>
> Id int
> Description string
> Active DateTime
> Inactive Nullable<DateTime>
> CreatedBy string
> CreatedDate DateTime
> ModifiedBy string
> ModifiedDate DateTime
> ```

I created a model that holds `IEnumerable` of each of the look-up tables and a `TypeGeneric`, which is the same structure but it adds a string `gType` (which will come into play in a moment). The types are all `ITypeModel`.

**Model**

```cs
public class TypeModels
{
    public IEnumerable<Type1> Type1 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Type2> Type2 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Type3> Type3 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Type4> Type4 { get; set; }

    public TypeGeneric TypeG { get; set; }
}
```

Through several failed attempts and learning some odd behavior of Controllers and Actions I finally was able to create "Generic" Action set that would allow me to handle all of my Types. However, it feels more of a hack then an actual solution. Is there is a better way of handling this?

**Controller**

```cs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TypeModels model = new TypeModels();

        model.Type1 = db.Type1.ToList();
        model.Type2 = db.Type2.ToList();
        model.Type3 = db.Type3.ToList();
        model.Type4 = db.Type4.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Create(string type)
    {
        TypeModels m = new TypeModels();
        m.TypeG = new TypeGeneric();
        m.TypeG.sType = type;

        createTypeView(m.TypeG);
        return View(m);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TypeModels m)
    {
        createType(m.TypeG);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

    public void createTypeView<T>(T type) where T:ITypeModel
    {
        type.DateActive = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void createType(TypeGeneric m)
    {
        ITypeModel model = null;
        model = castAndLoadITypeModel(model, m);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            model.CreatedDate = model.ModifiedDate = now;
            model.CreatedBy = model.ModifiedBy = user;

            if (model.DateActive < DateTime.Now)
            {
                model.DateActive = now;
            }

            db.Set(model.GetType()).Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public ITypeModel castAndLoadITypeModel(ITypeModel model, TypeGeneric type)
    {
        switch (type.sType)
        {
            case "1":
                model = new Type1();
                goto case "all";
            case "2":
                model = new Type2();
                goto case "all";
            case "3":
                model = new Type3();
                goto case "all";
            case "4":
                model = new Type4();
                goto case "all";
            case "all":
                loadType(model, type);
                break;
        }
        return model;
    }

    public void loadType(ITypeModel model, TypeGeneric m)
    {
        model.Description = m.Description;
        model.DateActive = m.DateActive;
    }
```

**Index View**

```html
@model TMS.Models.TypeModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <h3>Event Types</h3>
            <div>
                @{ WebGrid grid1 = new WebGrid(Model.Type1);}
                @grid1.GetHtml(
                    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                    selectedRowStyle: "webrid-selected-row",
                    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                    columns: grid1.Columns(
                    grid1.Column("Description", "Types"),
                    grid1.Column("DateActive", "Active"),
                    grid1.Column("DateInactive", "Inactive")
                    ))
            </div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", new { type = "1" })
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-1"></div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
        <h3>Dose Amounts</h3>
        <div>
            @{
                WebGrid grid2 = new WebGrid(Model.Type2);
            }
            @grid2.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
            selectedRowStyle: "webrid-selected-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: grid2.Columns(
            grid2.Column("Description")
            ))
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", new { type = "2" })

    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Create View**

```html
@model TMS.Models.TypeModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create " + Model;
}

<h2>Create @Model.TypeG.sType</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TypeG.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TypeG.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TypeG.Description, "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TypeG.DateActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TypeG.DateActive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TypeG.DateActive, "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TypeG.sType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "hide" } })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When the add button is clicked on the Index Page, it sends along a string value that tells me what Type was selected. I create and add a `GenericType` to my model and pass it to the Create View. The data is filled into this `GenericType` and when it is submitted I grab the string value and assign an `ITypeModel` the proper `TypeClass` and fill in the data using my `GenericType` values.

This solution works, but I have a sneak suspicion that there are better ways of handling this.

Searching online I found a few different ways of handling this, but most of those came from my failures. One was creating my own Controllers for generic Actions, which is really more work than I think its worth.

My other problem was attempting to use an Interface in my model, which the controller doesn't like at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle it via a generic base controller:

```
public abstract class TypeController<T> : Controller
    where T : ITypeModel, class, new()
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var type = new T();
        return View(type);
    }

    public ActionResult Create(T type)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            type.CreatedDate = type.ModifiedDate = now;
            type.CreatedBy = type.ModifiedBy = user;

            if (type.DateActive < DateTime.Now)
            {
                type.DateActive = now;
            }

            db.Set<T>().Add(type);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(type);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, subclass this controller for each type:

```
public class Type1Controller : TypeController<Type1>
{
}
```

Then, just link directly to the type being created:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create new Type 1", "Create", "Type1")
```

Comment: Would I have to make a controller for each Type?

Comment: Yes, this serves two purposes: 1) satisfying the type parameter for the generic class and 2) giving you a unique endpoint for routing. However, unless you need anything additional, the type-specific controller can be pretty much empty, as in the sample code above.